# SignalR taking too much time during first load

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

SignalR is taking too much time when called from the page. I have looked at almost all the material regarding transports, even tried switching to one mechanism like longpooling, hub issues, client hub issues but still no luck.

The hub is a remote class that is hosted in IIS and client is also hosted on the same

Below is my code for the client:

```
<script src='http://localhost:81/SignalRWebapp/signalr/hubs'></script>

$(function () {
    var tryingToReconnect = false;

    var messageHub = $.connection.messageHub;
    $.connection.hub.logging = true;

    messageHub.client.userLoggedIn = function (name, message) {
        console.log(name + ' ' + message);
    };

    messageHub.client.displayMessage = function (sender, message) {
        $("#searchNews").val(message);
    };

    
    $.connection.hub.start({
        jsonp: true,
        transport: 'webSockets'
    }).done(function () {
        // Wire up Send button to call NewContosoChatMessage on the server.
        console.log("Connected, transport = " + $.connection.hub.transport.name);
        
        $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
            var stringn = $("#searchNews").val();
            messageHub.server.sendMessage('ajsdh', stringn+"text");
        });
    }).fail(function (reason) {
        console.log("SignalR connection failed: " + reason);
    });
});
```

Here is the Hub code:

```
  public class MessageHub:Hub 
    {
        public void Login(string username)
        {
            // Notify all clients that a user is logged in
            Clients.All.userLoggedIn(username);
        }

        public async Task SendMessage(string sender, string message)
        {
            // Display the new message by calling displayMessage on all connected clients
            var id = Context.ConnectionId;
            await Clients.All.displayMessage(sender, message);
        }
    }
```

Startup class:

```
 public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR(new HubConfiguration
            {
                EnableJSONP = true,
                EnableJavaScriptProxies = true,
                EnableDetailedErrors = true
            });
        }
    }
```

One frustrating issue occurred due to this is none of my further requests from my webapp(client) is accepted, I have checked for the Network in chrome all the requests are moved into pending which are accepted only after the signalr connection is established(is this scenario expected?)

Below are the signalR logs:

```
[17:48:35] SignalR: Client subscribed to hub 'messagehub'.
jquery.signalR-2.4.1.js:86 [17:48:35] SignalR: Negotiating with '/SignalRWebapp/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=2.1&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22messagehub%22%7D%5D'.
jquery.signalR-2.4.1.js:86 [17:48:35] SignalR: Negotiating with '/SignalRWebapp/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=2.1&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22messagehub%22%7D%5D'.
jquery.signalR-2.4.1.js:86 [17:48:35] SignalR: webSockets transport starting.
jquery.signalR-2.4.1.js:86 [17:48:35] SignalR: Connecting to websocket endpoint 'ws://localhost:81/SignalRWebapp/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=2.1&connectionToken...'.
jquery.signalR-2.4.1.js:86 [17:48:35] SignalR: Websocket opened.
jquery.signalR-2.4.1.js:86 [17:48:35] SignalR: webSockets transport connected. Initiating start request.
```

What happens after this is my webapp(Client) is not able to perform any further requests(Stuck) as this start connection is not fulfilled yet.

Now after some time, I get these logs

```
[17:56:27] SignalR: The start request succeeded. Transitioning to the connected state.
jquery.signalR-2.4.1.js:86] SignalR: Now monitoring keep alive with a warning timeout of 13333.333333333332, keep alive timeout of 20000 and disconnecting timeout of 30000
```

I am new to this subject and this behavior of signalr is bugging me for some time now, can anyone please explain to me what is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it, Although the problem was in itself tricky, I had hosted all the applications(client, server, hub Application) into the same application pool in IIS which was the reason for its timing issue.